# Form submits even when there is an invalid input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to validate the text input in my html. I only want alphabets and spaces. In the beginning, the validation worked but now it is not and I cannot seem to find the problem. It still submits the form with the invalid field. Please see the code below

`index.html`

```
<div class="full-form">
    <form class=form-info action="cv.html" onsubmit="return handlesubmit()" >
    <div class="f-header">
        SIGN UP
    </div>
    
    <div class="bdetails">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="f_name" placeholder="First Name" onfocus="checkFName()" onblur="BlurFName()" required><br>
        <p class="error_message" id="First_em">Name must contain only alphabets(A-Z)</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </form>
```

`test.js`

```
function checkData(){
    if(BlurFName()){
   
    }
    return false;
}


function handlesubmit(){
   checkData();
        passvalue();
    

}
```

/*
Function to check if the name inputted is valid when the input is focused
*/

```
function checkFName(){
    let name_len=/^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    let fname= document.getElementById("f_name");
    if(!fname.value.match(name_len)){
        document.getElementById("First_em").style.display = "inline";
        return true;
    } 
};
```

/*
Function to check if the name inputted is valid when the input is blurred
*/

```
function BlurFName(){   
    let name_len=/^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    let fname= document.getElementById("f_name");

    if(fname.value.match(name_len)){
        document.getElementById("First_em").style.display = "none";
        return false;
    }
```

};

Comment: handlesubmit returns nothing.....

Comment: @epascarello okay. I  have changed the function handlesubmit() and this time it does not submit but after correcting the invalid input it still does not go through

Comment: Where is the return true/false? `function handlesubmit(){ let isValid = true; return isValid; }`

Comment: @epascarelloI I have tried that but after the valid input it's not submitting

Comment: than you are not returning true if it is valid

Answer (score 0):

With function handlesubmit you need to return false or true.

I suggest use

```
e.preventDefault();
```

to easier handle Form submiting

Comment: Thank you , i have tried that but it's not submitting

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from your validation method. You need to do something like this:

```js
function validateName () {
  const inp = document.getElementById("fname");
  const isValid = inp.value.trim().length > 0;
  inp.classList.toggle('error', !isValid);
  return isValid;
}

function validateGuess () {
  const inp = document.getElementById("guess");
  const isValid = +inp.value.trim() > 10;
  inp.classList.toggle('error', !isValid);
  return isValid;
}

function validate () {
  const isNameValid = validateName();
  const isGuessValid = validateGuess();
  return isNameValid && isGuessValid;
}
```

```css
.error { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
  <label for="fname">name</label> <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" /><br/>
  <label for="guess">guess</label> <input type="number" name="guess" id="guess" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```